# Manual Scheduler For Custom Post Type

Tags: posts, customization

I have a custom post type with a completely different interface (basically, I've removed all wordpress metaboxes and added my own). I am trying to build a schedule metabox for this custom post type (because I removed the original publish metabox). Should I do this over wp cron or use custom status, or?

Comment: Why have you removed native publishing method? What do you mean exactly by “schedule metabox”? How should that CPT be published?

Comment: I do not use the edit page interface provided from wordpress, instead I use a custom GUI and I use only the database functionality from wordpress.

Comment: Something like `wp_insert_post` but for scheduling available maybe?

Comment: so why don’t you use this function and set your posts as future?

Comment: will it work if I set future date? What if I want to update a post